# Difference between two numeric arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two numeric arrays say:

```
$x = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16);
and
$y = array(1,3,6);
```

How do I compute the diffidence between them. I'd like a result like:

```
$result = array(2,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16);
```

ie a numeric array return type, I have used `array_diff()`, and `array_assoc_diff()`
but i get a string array

thanks

Comment: What do you mean "i get a string array"? the `array_diff` functions does exactly what you are looking for...

Comment: You might be checking like `echo $result;`. Please check either `var_dump($result)` or print_r($result);

Answer (score 0):

Oh, tanks guys, i fixed the problem, had an error a somewhere in my code

this is actually the code:

```
<?php
    $schedule_id = $_POST['schedule_id'];;
    $query = " SELECT seat_selected FROM masstransit_reserve WHERE schedule_id = '".$schedule_id."' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbConn,$query) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbConn));

    $occupied_seats = array();
    foreach($result as $row){
        $occupied_seats[] = $row;
    }

    $seats = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16);



    $result1 = array_diff($seats, $occupied_seats);




    echo json_encode($result1);
?>
```

so because of the [] in this line $occupied_seats[] = $row;
i was getting the error.
I just removed it and it works well

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code:

```
$x = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16);

$y = array(1,3,6);

$z = array();
foreach ($x as $value) {
   if(!in_array($value, $y)) {
        $z[] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($z);
```